# How do you turn a string with url into a url that is clickable using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

```
url="https://fourminutebooks.com/book-summaries/"
driver.get(url)

fin_list = []
page_tabs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='post_title w4pl_post_title']")
for i in range(len(page_tabs)):
  page_tabs[i] = page_tabs[i].get_attribute("href")
  fin_list.append(page_tabs[i])

fin_list[0].click()
#html = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"header[class='entry-header page-header']")

print(fin_list)
```

I am trying to create a program that randomly emails me book summaries, and am having difficulty clicking on the link to get the HTML content. I have managed to get all the links, but they are saved as a string and I cannot click on one of the links without getting an error. **note the image below

[This is without trying to get the first element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMhcr.png)

Comment: There are 1101 links altogether. Do you intend to open all of them in tabs? I am sure performance would take a hit after a few iterations

Comment: No, the idea is to get one random link out of all of these each day and email it to myself and then remove that link from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
page_tabs = [x.get_attribute('href') for x in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='post_title w4pl_post_title']")]

driver.get(page[0])
```

To simply access a url from the list you can do.

Answer (score 0):

You can not turn a string to be a web element object.
These are definitely different objects.
As a user you can click a web element on a web page.
Similarly, Selenium can click on a web element. It can not click string or int.
In case you want to collect a list of clickable objects you have to collect a clickable web elements.
In your particular case you can keep a `page_tabs` list to click on `page_tabs[0]` element later with

```py
page_tabs[0].click()
```